# How is a syscall is defined in linux kernel? What's the relation between compat_sys_xxx and sys_xxx?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

In /include/linux/compat.h, I see a lot of compat_sys_xxx. Also, there is sys_xxx defined somewhere else. What's the relation between compat_sys_xxx and sys_xxx?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a compat entry, it almost certainly means that the system call prototype was changed and a version of the previous prototype was maintained for compatibility. Often you'll see that compat_sys_xxx just calls sys_xxx with the arguments converted appropriately (or both call a common function with slightly different conversions).

As a more or less random example, compat_sys_msgsnd takes three "int" arguments followed by a pointer to a compat_msgbuf structure (wherein the first - ostensibly "long" - field is forced to a 32-bit size). OTOH, sys_msgsnd lists the arguments in a different order and with argument types selected to morph appropriately for the architecture (i.e. long floats according to the natural long integer size, size_t replaces int in one place, etc).

No doubt the syscall interface was changed because the original interface was ambiguous in some way, when moved to a different (non-i386) architecture. The compat_ version allows existing binaries to continue working without modification.